# Procedure for creating an MvvmCross Store application for Windows 8.1 from scratch?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, mvvmcross, windows-8.1

Using Visual Studio 2013, I am creating a new Windows Store application for Windows 8.1 based on *MvvmCross*.

I first create my PCL *.Core* class library with view models according to the instructions in the *Core.txt* to-do file.

Next, I create my *.Store* application, now following the instructions in the *Windows Store UI.txt* to-do file. I do want to use the navigation framework, so I am replacing the `FirstView.xaml` page with a *Basic Page* `FirstView.xaml`.

According to the instructions, the `LayoutAwarePage` class should inherit `MvxStorePage` but since the `LayoutAwarePage.cs` is no longer included in VS2013/8.1 Store projects, I am instead changing my `FirstView.xaml` page to be an `MvxStorePage` type:

```
<views:MvxStorePage x:Name="pageRoot" x:Class="App.Store.Views.FirstView"
 ... >
...
</views:MvxStorePage>
```

With this change, *FirstView* is displayed when I start the app, but the view-model bindings do not work! What would be the correct procedure for setting up the MvvmCross view-view model bindings in a Windows Store 8.1 app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems I forgot one part of the instructions in the *Windows Store UI.txt* to-do file:

> Add a views folder and a view - xaml.cs and .xaml based on BasicPage - this will add 5 files to the Common folder.
> - Change the Common/LayoutAwarePage.cs inheritance to Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsStore.Views.MvxStorePage
>     **- Change the Common/LayoutAwarePage.cs - remove the OnNavigatedTo and OnNavigatedFrom handlers**
>
>     - Add some content for your Xaml - e.g. `<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Hello}"/>`

If I remove the `OnNavigatedTo` and `OnNavigatedFrom` overrides from the `FirstView.xaml.cs` file, `FirstViewModel` will be correctly bound to `FirstView`.

So, as far as I can tell, the instructions for Windows Store apps on Windows 8.1 should be:

- In every *view .xaml* file, change `<Page>` to `<views:MvxStorePage>`.
- In every *view .xaml.cs* file, delete the `OnNavigatedTo` and `OnNavigatedFrom` overrides.

**EDIT**
Additionally, to avoid view-model mix-ups, it might also be a good idea to remove the `DefaultViewModel` property and associated `defaultViewModel` field from the *.xaml.cs* file, and also remove the `DataContext` attribute from the `<views:MvxStorePage>` tag in the *.xaml* file, since the relevant `DataContext` will anyhow be set by *MvvmCross*.

Comment: you beat me to the answer. The problem is that those overrides don't call their base methods - like `base.OnNavigatedTo(e)`. This prevents MvvmCross from intercepting the navigation and loading the ViewModel. I did informally ask one of the MS guys if this could be changed - the answer was no.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @Stuart. Is it safe to delete the overrides in the views? Or will there be navigation problems "down the road" since the `navigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo/From` methods are not called?

Comment: The reason those calls are there is for state loading/saving - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj655410.aspx - I'm afraid this area is a little unclear to me... it looks better now than in 8.0, but in practice you may need to experiment a little when/if you decide you need to persist page/viewmodel state in your app.

Comment: I think this should be added in the txt file, I had to search for the answer as soon as it came up to me that this folder wasn't added.